# How to implement naive batch gradient descent?

Tags: gradient-descent, chainer

everyone. I have a question about the implement of gradient descent. I have found several optimizers, like ada_grad, adam, sgd and so on, they're perfect. But I'm attempting to implement the naive gradient method batch gradient descent that is with the fix learning rate and acts on the whole examples in each batch. How to do it? Wait for your help. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using large enough batch-size and SGD? It is equivalent to simple Gradient Descent method.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new in Chainer. I can't understand the mechanism completely. I think that SGD updates the parameters just for one example. So, even though I increases the number of batch-size, it make nonsenses for the gradient descent process. Isn't it ? Or, I misunderstand something. Following code is from program. Is it possible for you to give some advice? Thk. 
     for samples in train: 
        forward feed;
        if count >= batchsize:
            model.cleargrads()
            accum_loss.backward()
            optimizer.update()
            total_loss += float(accum_loss.data)

Comment: > I think that SGD updates the parameters just for one example.

No, SGD updates the parameters for whole minibatch. Therefore, if you can feed all the examples in one minibatch at once, it will be equivalent with batch gradient descent.

Comment: Thks for your elaboration.